# luaotfload | load : FATAL ERROR (output excerpt on the terminal after the lua run)

Tags: luatex, plain-tex, opmac

On a texlive2019 distribution, tex engine luatex, fonts used recognized by other engines (xetex, pdftex, csplain). Macros of OPmac - plaintex, no latex.

Sourcefile:

```
                \input opmac
                \input luaotfload.sty                                       
                \font\tenrm="DejaVu Serif"                                                
                \tenrm 
                Hello                                                              
                \bye
```

Terminal output, all after luatex $file run:

```
: 0 ~/proj: luatex test_opmac_luatex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test_opmac_luatex (/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/a4.tex
Aug. 2018, with additional "mtex" styling
(/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/eplain.tex)
(/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/ams-math.tex
FONT: AMS math fonts - \mathchardef's prepared, 12 math families preloaded.)
OPmac: etex.src macros detected (/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/opmac-luatex.tex)
(/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/fontfam.tex
(/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/fontfam-global.tex))
(/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/cs-libertine.tex
(/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/ff-mac.tex (/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/luafonts.tex
processing ltluatex.lua (3)

luaotfload | load : FATAL ERROR
luaotfload | load :   × Failed to load module "luaotfload-database.lua".
luaotfload | load :   × Error message:
luaotfload | load :     × "[string \"-- luatex-core security and io overloads  
.......\"]:45: bad argument #1 to 'io_open' (string expected, got nil)".

stack traceback:
        ...019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:181: in upvalue 'loadmodule'
        ...019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:257: in local 'initialize'
        ...019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:307: in field 'main'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk

+ 1! ~/proj:
```

### A basic run:

```
                1 %\input a4                                                                 
                2 %\input opmac-luafonts                                                     
                3 %\input luaotfload.sty                                                                                            
                4                                                                            
                5 Hello                                                                      
                6                                                                            
                7 \bye
```

-------- and

### the terminal output after the luatex run on the above file:

```
: 1! ~/proj: luatex basic-demo                                                                                                          
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)                                                                                          
 restricted system commands enabled.                                                                                                    
(./basic-demo [1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdft                                                         
ex.map}])</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr                                                         
10.pfb>                                                                                                                                 
Output written on basic-demo.pdf (1 page, 10337 bytes).                                                                                 
Transcript written on basic-demo.log.                                                                                                   
+ 0 ~/proj
```

---

Notes:

The \input a4 is a renamed opmac.tex file, runs without errors using xetex, pdfcsplain, pdftex, the three other engines give no complaints.
Uncommenting the line "\input luaotfload.sty" touching nothing else in the above minimal example throws the error as printed above.

### Below printed the tail of the log file (all 48 lines) after run on the minimal example with "\input luaotfload.sty" uncommented:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)  (format=luatex 2019.6.5)  10 FEB 2020 13:04
 restricted system commands enabled.
**basic-demo
(./basic-demo (/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/luaotfload.sty
(/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/ltluatex.tex
File: ltluatex.tex 2018/10/21 v1.1i LuaTeX support for plain TeX (core) 
\e@alloc@attribute@count=\count277
\e@alloc@ccodetable@count=\count278
\e@alloc@luafunction@count=\count279
\e@alloc@whatsit@count=\count280
\e@alloc@bytecode@count=\count281
\e@alloc@luachunk@count=\count282
\catcodetable@initex=\catcodetable1
\catcodetable@string=\catcodetable2
\catcodetable@latex=\catcodetable3
\catcodetable@atletter=\catcodetable4
)
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/lu
atex-cache/generic-dev/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2020-01-26.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/fontloader-2020-01-26.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.11”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
luaotfload | load : FATAL ERROR
luaotfload | load :   × Failed to load module "luaotfload-database.lua".
luaotfload | load :   × Error message:
luaotfload | load :     × "[string \"-- luatex-core security and io overloads .
......\"]:45: bad argument #1 to 'io_open' (string expected, got nil)".
```

### lualatex terminal output as suggested:

```
restricted system commands enabled.                                                                                                    
(./latex-example.tex                                                                                                                    
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>           




luaotfload | load : FATAL ERROR                                                                                                         
luaotfload | load :   × Failed to load module "luaotfload-database.lua".                                                                
luaotfload | load :   × Error message:                                                                                                  
luaotfload | load :     × "[string \"-- luatex-core security and io overloads .......\"]:45: bad argument #1 to 'io_open' (string expect
ed, got nil)".
```

stack traceback:

```
    ...019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:181: in upvalue 'loadmodule'                                        
    ...019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:257: in local 'initialize'                                          
    ...019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:307: in field 'main'                                                
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk                                                                                                   

    : 1! ~/proj:
```

### lualatex output of the logfile:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)  (format=lualatex 2019.6.5)  10 FEB 2020 14:36
 restricted system commands enabled.
**latex-example.tex
(./latex-example.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/lu
atex-cache/generic-dev/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2020-01-26.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex/fontloader-2020-01-26.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 3
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 4
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.11”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / callback 
handling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
luaotfload | load : FATAL ERROR
luaotfload | load :   × Failed to load module "luaotfload-database.lua".
luaotfload | load :   × Error message:
luaotfload | load :     × "[string \"-- luatex-core security and io overloads .
......\"]:45: bad argument #1 to 'io_open' (string expected, got nil)".
```

### tlmgr output:

```
+ 0 ~: tlmgr info "unicode-data"
package:     unicode-data
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Unicode data and loaders for TeX
longdesc:    This bundle provides generic access to Unicode Consortium data for TeX use. It contains a set of text files provided by the Unicode Consortium which are currently all from Unicode 8.0.0, with the exception of MathClass.txt which is not currently part of the Unicode Character Database. Accompanying these source data are generic TeX loader files allowing this data to be used as part of TeX runs, in particular in building format files. Currently there are two loader files: one for general character set up and one for initialising XeTeX character classes as has been carried out to date by unicode-letters.tex. The source data are distributed in accordance with the license stipulated by the Unicode Consortium. The bundle as a whole is co-ordinated by the LaTeX3 Project as a general resource for TeX users.
installed:   Yes
revision:    52961
sizes:       doc: 13k, run: 2681k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.11
cat-license: lppl1.3c
cat-topics:  latex3 unicode
cat-contact-repository: https://github.com/latex3/unicode-data
collection:  collection-basic

+ 0 ~:
```

### ---- end tlmgr -----

Existing files:

- 0 ~: ls -la /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/unicode-data/CaseFolding.txt
  84K -rw-r--r-- 1 m___ m___ 81K Aug 13 22:54 /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/unicode-data/CaseFolding.txt
- 0 ~:
- 0 ~: ls -la /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/tlpobj/unicode-data.tlpobj
  4K -rw-rw-r-- 1 m___ m___ 3K Feb  8 13:37 /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/tlpobj/unicode-data.tlpobj
- 0 ~:

  ### --- end existing files ----

### tlmgr:

: 1! ~: /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update
tlmgr update: specify --list, --all, --self, or a list of package names.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
+ 1! ~: /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update luatex
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirror.ftn.uns.ac.rs/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates available
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFSYSVAR in scalar chomp at /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 862.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFSYSCONFIG in scalar chomp at /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 863.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFLOCAL in scalar chomp at /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 864.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFDIST in scalar chomp at /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 865.
Use of uninitialized value $TEXMFDIST in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 876.
+ 0 ~:

Comment: works fine for me. show your log-file.

Comment: can you run a small latex document with lualatex or does it fail too?

Comment: is your version of the unicode-data package up-to-date (and is it actually installed?)

Comment: See above for the minimal example, and the output of the log file. The line "\input luaotfload.sty" , what is read inside the luaotfload.sty file is probably causing the error, but my acquaintance with lua is still nil.

Comment: I asked for a *latex*  example. Run `lualatex hello`  where hello.tex contains `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}hello\end{document}`.

Comment: On your suggestion, and thanks to attend me, the output of the run on the terminal: see the main area of the question for the output.

Comment: As I already asked: do you have the unicode-data package installed and is it up-to-date? Your latex is quite outdated so probably this is true for other packages too. luaotfload 3.12 requires up-to-date unicode-data files.

Comment: Added, lualatex run output on your minimal suggestion. Added the output of the logfile.

Comment: Addended the output of tlmgr, to status the unicode-data package.

Comment: @m___ What does `kpsewhich CaseFolding.txt` show?

Comment: Latest "tlmgr update --all" is today's.

Comment: kpsewhich CaseFolding.txt exits with an error, shows nothing.

Comment: @m___ Then please start by reinstalling `unicode-data`. The installation seems broken. Run `tlmgr install --reinstall unicode-data` as root.

Comment: : 1! ~: sudo tlmgr install --reinstall luatex
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/m___/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5604.
+ 1! ~:

Comment: You are using Debian/Ubuntu, have the Debian TeX Live package installed and additionally a local install of vanilla TeX Live, right?

Comment: What's your `$PATH`? (`echo $PATH`)

Comment: Both, /usr/local/texlive/texlive2019 installed using tlmgr . And the trisquel distro (Debian TeX) installed using apt-get install texlive . There must be some wrong environmental pointers of texlive. Xetex, pdftex, pdfcsplain engines all show the latest and run error free.

Comment: @m___ The problem is that `unicode-data` is missing. Normally you could fix that by using `tlmgr install unicode-data`, but in your case `tlmgr` seems to call the `tlmgr` from Debian TeX, therefore installing `unicode-data` in the wrong texmf tree.

Comment: /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/m___/.texmf/tex/mtex:/usr/bin:/home/m___/.bin:/usr/bin/mh:/usr/local/sbin Seems correct as the location of the texlive binaries are indeed the ones needed.

Comment: Do the files `/usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/tlpobj/unicode-data.tlpobj` and `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/unicode-data/CaseFolding.txt` exists?

Comment: + 1! ~: which tlmgr 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr
+ 0 ~: file tlmgr Being the correct one?!

Comment: Both files, do exist at these locations see the main area of the question for confirmation on the output of "ls -la"

Comment: Could this lead somewhere, the output of tlmgr, see the main question area. The uninitialized values part.

Comment: Values: + 0 ~: kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
/home/m___/.texmf
+ 0 ~: kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var
+ 0 ~: kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSCONFIG
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-config
+ 0 ~: kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
+ 0 ~: kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFDIST
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist
+ 0 ~: